# Reading A File in Hexidecimal and Coverting it to Decimal

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When Reading a file containing base 16 numbers my Scanner is only reading the even numbers, throwing the No Such Element Exception on odd numbers... I am new to java so this may be simple but i am at a loss... my current code is as follows...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class HexToDecimalConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner HexFile = new Scanner(new File("Hexidecimal.txt"));

            do {
                String Hex = HexFile.next();
                System.out.println(Hex);
                int outputDecimal = Integer.parseInt(Hex, 16);
                System.out.println(outputDecimal);
            } while (HexFile.next() != "  ");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundExc) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException IOExc) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException noSuchElementExc){
            System.out.println("No Such Element");
            System.exit(0);
        }


    {
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition:

```
} while (HexFile.next() != "  ");
```

also reads a hex number and discards it (because you don't store its return value anywhere). This explains why only the even numbers are printed by your code.

Instead use the following condition:

```
} while (HexFile.hasNext());
```

[`Scanner.hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--) just tests if there are more tokens but does not read or discard the next token if there are more.

Also you might want to use a `while` loop which tests before reading because the file might not contain anything, so for example:

```
while (HexFile.hasNext()) {
    String Hex = HexFile.next();
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you twice call to HexFile.next()
Begin with changing your code like this:

```
    String Hex = HexFile.next();
    while (Hex!= "  ") {
        System.out.println(Hex);
        int outputDecimal = Integer.parseInt(Hex, 16);
        System.out.println(outputDecimal);
        String Hex = HexFile.next();
    }
```